# Are questions about teaching math to children who have some disabilities on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

I don't teach school math but as a part of my voluntary activities in some related associations sometimes I am in this special situation.

**Question 1.** Are questions about teaching math to children who have some disabilities on-topic here?

**Question 2.** Is there any professional in this particular subject here?

**Question 3.** What should be the title of the related tag?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Currently on MESE? I'm not sure, but such researchers certainly exist at both ends of the spectrum (the other end being gifted education). 3. I think quid's suggestion of *special-needs-education* ought to suffice.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to #1 is "absolutely".

For #2, I have no idea.  The only way to find out is to post a question about teaching disabled students on the main site, and see whether you get answers from any experts.

For #3, I would suggest a "special-education" or "special-needs" tag (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_education)), although I have no idea whether these terms are used outside of the United States.

Comment: re 3, at least it seems also common in UK http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_education_in_the_United_Kingdom (I delete my near identical answer.) Just I would not use only special-education as it could be interpreted in a different way.

Comment: Is the question 2 related to the main or meta forum? It seems it is about users of this site and so will be closed in the main site.

Comment: @SaintGeorg I have edited my description of #2 for clarity.  I'm not suggesting asking on the main site whether there are any experts on special needs education -- I'm suggesting asking a question *about* special needs education, with the hope that it might be answered by an expert.

Comment: On the tag name: special-needs-education should still fit below the length limit for tags. It would then follow the general pattern of having -education and the 'needs' for clarification.

Comment: In the UK 'special needs' is a common phrase, but 'special education' is not so common.